# Find the complement of the expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

```
(a+c)(a+b')(a'+b+c')
```

i used DeMorgan to simplify and got a'c'+a'b+ab'c, how can i simplify further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got doesn't simplify any further!

If you were to do a K-map you'll find that your expression a'c'+a'b+ab'c is the 'simplest' one.